# visual studio code with pylance cannot resolve imports while using docker

Tags: python, docker, visual-studio-code, pylance

I set up visual studio code to use a docker instance provided to me. For some reason pylance cannot locate some of my imports even though I added the import path in the settings.json for user, container and workspace. I am wondering if anybody has experience with that and can help me. Adding some pictures that shows the issue. In particular i am interested in pylance locating the cocotb library. Thanks for any help
Amish

[image]

[image]

Comment: I think you should remove `~` from the paths since that's going to be expanded to your user home folder which you've already given